# valid MySQL subquery syntax and placement

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, subquery

I've never figured out several syntax things about SQL subqueries. Mainly I'm interested in where in the parent query is it valid to place a subquery.

here's an example which throws an error:

```
SELECT 
  sum(votes.vote) AS sum, 
  votes.vote IS NOT NULL AS did_i_vote, 
  purchase_id, subject, full_name 
FROM (
  SELECT vote FROM votes 
  where votes.acct_id=3 AND 
    votes.column_name='purchase_id'
) votes  
RIGHT JOIN items_purchased 
  ON votes.parent_id=items_purchased.purchase_id  
JOIN accounts 
  ON items_purchased.purchaser_account_id=accounts.acct_id   
JOIN items 
  ON items_purchased.item_id=items.folder_id   
WHERE purchase_id='2' 
GROUP BY items_purchased.purchase_id
```

How do I make this query work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `subquery` must select every `column` that you wish to reference afterwards.

```
SELECT 
  sum(votes.vote) AS sum, 
  votes.vote IS NOT NULL AS did_i_vote, 
  purchase_id, subject, full_name 
FROM (
  SELECT vote, parent_id FROM votes 
  where votes.acct_id=3 AND 
    votes.column_name='purchase_id'
) votes  
RIGHT JOIN items_purchased 
  ON votes.parent_id=items_purchased.purchase_id  
JOIN accounts 
  ON items_purchased.purchaser_account_id=accounts.acct_id   
JOIN items 
  ON items_purchased.item_id=items.folder_id   
WHERE purchase_id='2' 
GROUP BY items_purchased.purchase_id
```

Is what I would assume (note that I select `vote` and `parent_id` in the subquery)

Comment: hi Angelo, thanks for your answer. So the subquery can be anywhere as long as you `SELECT` each of the field names used in other parts of the query?

Comment: @timpeterson No, the `subquery` can't be everywhere, but whenever you could use a `table` (or a value as long as the subquery returnes only one result), you can use a `subquery`. You just have to make sure that the `subquery` returns the right amount of result. (e.G. if you use one between `SELECT` and `FROM` it _must_ return only one result per call. But if you use one in the `FROM` clause (like you do here) you must be sure to select everything that you want to use later on)

Comment: By `table` do you mean `column`?

Comment: @MattFenwick No, what I meant is this. One can use a `subquery` when one can use a `table`. And one can use a `subquery` when you could use a `column` but only if that `subquery` returns exactly one row.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was actually referring to the first line: `You must select every **table** you wish to reference in your subquery`

Answer (score 2):

One error is in the `GROUP BY` part!

In the `SELECT`, you can only have the columns displayed in the `GROUP BY` and agregate functions of columns that are not there.

---

Check [THIS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) info!

Comment: hi aF, thanks. I'm still a bit confused by your answer, would you mind explaining in a bit more detail?

Comment: @timpeterson check THIS: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: To clarify:  **MySQL does allow selection of non group by, non-aggregate columns** unless the SQL mode is set to something more strict (for instance,  `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`).